# Spotify Web API Node - no token provided error

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

I'm 100% sure my access token is right but everytime i run my code its saying to me "no token provided" why is that? It's working about 30 minutes ago...

PS: I refreshed my access token i tried it many times. So its not expired too...

```
var spotifyWebApiNode = require("spotify-web-api-node")
var spotifyApi = new spotifyWebApiNode();

spotifyApi.setAccessToken = "<my access token here>";

spotifyApi.getArtistAlbums('43ZHCT0cAZBISjO8DG9PnE').then(
  function(data) {
    console.log('Artist albums', data.body);
  },
  function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
);
```

EDIT: I wrote all scopes, all permissions are included.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
spotifyApi.setAccessToken('<your_access_token>');
```

instead of this:

```
spotifyApi.setAccessToken = "<my access token here>";
```

https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node#usage